# How to debug Laravel memory error with no stack trace?

Tags: php, laravel

I have been seeing this error in my Laravel log recently:

```
[2020-01-13 08:59:36] production.ERROR: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16384 bytes) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 1): Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16384 bytes) at /home/fantas52/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:330)
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
"}
```

That's it - no stack trace, so I have no idea where the problem is coming from. I can see it's a memory issue and that it's related to the database, but can I find out where in the application the problem is starting and how to remedy it?

This is the first time I'm seeing something like this with 0 stack trace items.

The application seems to be working fine on the surface and I don't see any issues with the contents and function of the website, but I would like to figure out this error nonetheless.

Comment: I'd suggest the error was coming from Connection.php:330, as per the message. Presumably there's no further trace because that was the lowest-level PHP code in the stack anyway (maybe it's from a function which is compiled as native code underneath (e.g. many core PHP functions are written in C)). What happens on that line of your script?

Comment: @ADyson Well, clearly, but Connection.php:330 is a method that "runs a select statement against the database" according to the comment. My question is, how am I supposed to find out which select statement is the problematic one? There's no "that line of my script" since this is in Laravel's core files.

Comment: Do you have a query log to check against? If not I'd suggest setting one up just to see what timestamps coincide between them.

Comment: " this is in Laravel's core files"...they are still readable and modifiable source code in your application. It's odd that it doesn't trace back to anything else, I agree (although that could be due to some dodgy re-throwing of exceptions, either in your code or Laravel's, which can easily screw up the stack. So if that's fixable, fix it and it might help with the logging). But since that source is modifiable, you could add some perfunctory extra logging to it temporarily, in order to log what SQL statement is being executed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got the same problem as me:

- Laradock or other Docker containers
- No errors
- No logs
- Laravel request eats our all your memory in docker and killed silently
- You even tried to debug your code with xDebug and nothing happened after Exception

The reason is `xDebug 3.0` with `develop` enabled, it prints detailed info about the exceptions (`Any exception`) and in the case of Laravel take a lot of memory, even 3GB not enough, it dies, without printing any info about it.

Just disable xDebug, at least develop, and it will be fine.